# ActiveRecord: sort of complicated query with nested associations and sorting

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Alrigth, so I'm not sure if this isn't too specific... But I really don't have a clue how to construct such a query, neither in AR, nor in SQL. So here's the situation:

- I have a `User` model. `User` has_many `Project`s. A `Project`, in turn, have a following associations:
- `Project` has_one `BasicEvent`
- `Project` had_many `AdditionalEvent`s
- `BasicEvent` and `AdditionalEvent` classes are built on inheritance from a AR model class, `Event`

Now, the goal is this: on my view, I need:

- access to all `Project`s count per `User`
- access to all `Event`s count, where `happened_at` attribute in `nil`
- have all the `User`s sorted, by the count of `Event`s, where `happened_at` attribute in `nil`

I made a couple of attempts at it so far, but didn't really get too far... I will appreciate any help with this complicated (at least from my perspective) query.

Comment: can you more specify what you want i am little bit confused with your count per User and other

Comment: Not sure, but I'll try. I want to know the count of `Project`s a `User` has. And also count of `Event`s per `User` (but there isn't a direct association between these two, it sort of happens via `Project`). And finally, I want all the `User`s to be ordered by the count of `Event`s. I hope that helps.

Comment: is there any association between project and Event???? and there should be association from user to has many events thorough project. source would be event

Comment: There are associations between `Project` and `Event`, but the `Event` is then further subclassed, as described above. There isn't any association between `User` and `Event` at all, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you looked into the use of `counter_cache` on rails.  [This blog](http://yerb.net/blog/2014/03/13/three-easy-steps-to-using-counter-caches-in-rails/) covers the basics on how to set one up.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't think I want to build those.. This seems to be needed for only one query.

Comment: this is pretty doable in sql, either ctes or subqueries would be easiest. Basically you need to count() all your Event subclass relationships with group by project first, then sum() them with a group by User. -- I know nothing about AR though. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can start from code like:

```
# -*- frozen-string-literal: true -*-
class UserStatService
  SELECT_CLAUSE = <<~SQL
    (SELECT count(1) FROM projects WHERE user_id=users.id) AS projects_count,
    (SELECT count(1) FROM events WHERE (happened_at IS NULL)
      AND (project_id IN (SELECT id FROM projects WHERE user_id=users.id)
    ) AS events_count,
    users.*
  SQL

  def call
    User
      .select( SELECT_CLAUSE )
      .order( 'events_count' )
  end
end
```

Each `User` instance in resultset will have `projects_count` and `events_count` attributes.

Also any kind of cache (`counter_cache` or handmade) is recommended. Because the query is not expected to be fast.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `basic_events` and `additional_events` have essentially the same columns, a great solution to this problem would be to change your database/app to use [single table inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html).

Assuming you're using Rails 5.x your models would look like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects
  has_many :basic_events, through: :projects
  has_many :additional_events, through: :projects
end
```

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :basic_event
  has_many :additional_events
end
```

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
end
```

```
class BasicEvent < Event
  belongs_to :project
end
```

```
class AdditionalEvent < Event
  belongs_to :project
end
```

---

This way, there are only three tables involved `users`, `projects` and `events`. Your `events` table will have a `:type` column where you can specify if it's `basic` or `additional`.

---

For your queries:

> access to all Projects count per User

```
User
  .select("users.*, count(projects.id) AS projects_count")
  .joins(:projects)
  .group('users.id')
  .order('projects_count DESC')
```

Using select like this give you access to a `:projects_count` method on each User object returned in this active record relation, so if you assigned this query to a variable called `users_with_projects_count` you could do `users_with_projects_count.first.projects_count` and it would return the number of projects associated with that user.

> access to all Events count, where happened_at attribute in nil

```
User
  .select("users.*, count(events.id) AS events_count")
  .joins(:events)
  .where('events.happened_at IS NULL')
  .group('users.id')
```

You can access `:events_count` the same way you did `:projects_count` in the last example.

> have all the Users sorted, by the count of Events, where happened_at attribute in nil

```
User
  .select("users.*, count(events.id) AS events_count")
  .joins(:events)
  .where('events.happened_at IS NULL')
  .group('users.id')
  .order('events_count DESC')
```

You use the same query as the last example just add an `:order`.

Answer (score 0):

Projects count per User: `Project.group(:user_id).count`

Events count, where `happened_at` attribute in `nil`: `Event.where(happened_at: nil).count`

Users sorted, by the count of Events, where `happened_at` attribute in `nil`: This is the trickiest but it's also not particularly difficult:

```
User.
  select("users.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events WHERE user_id = users.id AND happened_at IS NULL) AS unhappened_events_count").
  order("unhappened_events_count DESC")
```

This is not a particularly efficient query but it should do its job well for several thousand records (easily) – especially if you set an index on `user_id` and `happened_at` in the `events` table.